# Keep a single file's permissions when using install() in CMake

Tags: installation, cmake

In KDE, I adjusted a macro to compile and install Python files, but I'm having problem with it keeping the files' permissions.

To be more clear, the offendling line in the macro is

```
install(FILES ${SOURCE_FILE} DESTINATION ${DESTINATION_DIR})
```

which works for 99% of the cases.

In one case, though I have a Python file marked as executable (+x, I'm talking about Linux here) in the source directory, which then is symlinked to the installation's binary dir. Since install() does not preserve permissions, the execute bit is stripped from it, and this causes all sorts of problems later on.

Is it possible to keep the file's permissions, or to read them and set them accordingly? I would hate to use a manual `chmod` command since it's not portable.

EDIT: I do not want to make all files installed by this macro executable, as this would be pointless.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can install files with `+x` permission using

```
install(PROGRAMS ...
```

command.

Alternatively, you can install whole directory preserving file permissions:

```
install(DIRECTORIES ... USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS)
```

[See documentation](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3ainstall) for install command for more info.